# What open indexing services compete with Web of Science

Tags: citations, open-access, indexing

As far as  I know, the only indexing services which track citation across journals and data repositories are accessed for a fee. Are there any free-to-use databases of article or data citation indices ?

Comment: No. They exist but getting numbers from such indexing services would be fraudulent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but you've just made me more curious. Could you please give me the names of any that you know of that _do_ exist ? I know about Scopus and Web of Science (and of course, google Scholar) - any others ?

Comment: There are few fraudulent websites that keep track of citations for predatory journals. One of which is Scientific Journal Impact Factor (SJIF).

Comment: @Coder , mind explaining why fraudulent? I don't follow your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

I work for a biomedical literature database - Europe PMC, which makes citation data freely available. You can access it programmatically, via the articles API (https://europepmc.org/RestfulWebService#cites). This resource also tracks data citations for over 20 different public resources: https://europepmc.org/Help#trackdatacit